# Google feed api integration with iPhone/Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, search, rss, google-feed-api

I am building an RSS Reader. Some of the existing ones out there (for example, Pulse News for iPhone/iPad) have a search box where you can search for some term (example - "sports") and it will return a list of feeds that match your search criteria. So in this example, you type in "sports", and it searches and then comes back with ESPN.com's news feed, Yahoo! Sports' news feed, etc. etc.

After initial research, I found out that Google feed API does the same.
https://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/reference.html#findFeeds

However, I cant figure out how to use the google feed api. It returns the xml that i need to parse but the part I am confused is how to call the API and where to catch the xml response. Can some one post a tutorial or some help on how to integrate it.

Comment: Check [this tutorial](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-building-advanced-rss-reader/), and try doing some research, there are tons of guides and tutorials out there.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. But, I am able to show the RSS. What i want is an API which can return the list of RSS links when searched by a keyword like google feed API.

Comment: This [API](http://www.rssmicro.com/api.web) may help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a suitable solution with "Google Feed API" itself. They also have a JSON API(wow!!) which returns the JSON file for any query fired..
Here is the link:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?v=1.0&q=

e.g:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?v=1.0&q=News